# How to group by some column and show grouped value within existed another column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I would like to implement grouping, where values I need group by, may be shown within other existed column.

Please, see screenshot:[image: Sample]

How can I do it by SSRS v14.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STart by building your report with the details rows, then right-click the detail row in the row group panel below the main report design.

Do "Add Group" then "Parent Group". Choose the field that contains Buy/Sell and tick the "Add group header" option.

A new column will be added with the buy/sell field added. Delete this new column and then in the original column above instrument name, click the cell and choose the Buy/Sell field.

This should give you what you want.