# SSRS 2016 arrange groups as header

Tags: reporting-services

I trying to format an SSRS 2016 report such that the groups are displayed as a header while the rest (non grouped) fields are tabular like a normal spreadsheet.  For example, say I have the following dataset:

```
Group1 Group2 Group3 Detail1 Detail2 Detail3
Group1 Group2 Group3 Detail1 Detail2 Detail3
Group1 Group2 Group3 Detail1 Detail2 Detail3
......
```

I want to layout a report similar to this

```
    Group1Value1    
        Group2Value1
           Group3Value1
    Detail1Value1   Detail2Value1   Detail3Value1
    Detail1Value2   Detail2Value2   Detail3Value2
    Detail1Value3   Detail2Value3   Detail3Value3


    Group1Value1    
        Group2Value1
           Group3Value2
    Detail1Value4   Detail2Value4   Detail3Value4
    Detail1Value5   Detail2Value5   Detail3Value5
    Detail1Value6   Detail2Value6   Detail3Value6


    Group1Value1    
        Group2Value2
           Group3Value2
    Detail1Value7   Detail2Value7   Detail3Value7
    Detail1Value8   Detail2Value8   Detail3Value8
    Detail1Value9   Detail2Value9   Detail3Value9
....
```

I don't know how to do this with SSRS.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where do you get your Group1Value1 ..Group2Value2 etc., from? It's not part of your dataset?

Comment: See my answer here from a similar question asked today. You will need to repeat for each group but the process is the same. If this makes no sense, comment and I'll do a full answer.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886020/how-to-group-by-some-column-and-show-grouped-value-within-existed-another-column/48886159#48886159

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks that helped! I added another + in your answer on the other link.